# How to pass different event handlers for the same event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events

I have a react-native component which is rendering 2 Icons for **marking a favorite** and **writing a comment** as shown below:

```
function RenderDish(props) {
const dish = props.dish;

if (dish != null) {
    return (
        <Card featuredTitle={dish.name} image={{ uri: baseUrl + dish.image }}>
            <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                {dish.description}
            </Text>
            <View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Icon raised reverse name={props.favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'} type='font-awesome' color='#f50'
                    onPress={() => props.favorite ? console.log('Aleady Favorite') : props.onFavorite()} />
                <Icon raised reverse name='pencil' type='font-awesome' color='#3b5998'
                    onPress={() => props.onComment()} />
            </View>
        </Card>
    );
}
else {
    return (<View></View>);
}}
```

I am calling this functional component from the outer component as shown below:

```
<RenderDish dish={this.props.dishes.dishes[+dishId]}
                favorite={this.props.favorites.some(el => el === dishId)}
                onFavorite={() => this.markFavorite(dishId)}
                onComment={() => this.toggleModal()} />
```

I have already implemented the `toggleModal()` and the `markFavorite()` methods and everything is working as expected **but** my question is: Is there any other way of passing 2 or more different event handlers through a single prop ? For eg. Is there any way to say something like: `<RenderDish dish={xyz} onPress={()=> handler1 AND handler2}`. Or is there any elegant alternative to what I have done(if I had 5 buttons I would need 5 props :( ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your handlers in a single function and call the function in onPress.
or just

```
onPress={()=> {handler1, handler2}}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit ? How would I call only one of them when the corresponding event has occured ?

Comment: onPress={(e)=> myFunction(e)} 

myFunction = (e) => {
if(e.target.id === 'firstEventId') {}
else {}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. Pass the handler methods as an object in a props.

```
function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.onPress.handler1} >Handler1</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={props.onPress.handler2} >Handler2</button>
    </div>

  );
}


class Home extends Component {


  handler1() {
    console.log('handler 1');
  }

  handler2() {
    console.log('handler 2');
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onPress={{ handler1: this.handler1, handler2: this.handler2 }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you’ve done it is probably the most common way and perfectly acceptable.

It’s not generally a problem if there are only a few handlers (and they aren’t being passed deeply).

You *could* bundle them into an object and single prop, but I don’t typically see it done that way and I don’t think there’s a strong benefit.

You can also pass in multiple props as a single spread object *without* having to bundle them into a single prop.

If you start getting a more handlers than you’re comfortable with, then that would probably be a good time to look at how you’re handling your state management. You may be better off with a reducer and dispatching actions at that point.

---

### Update

A few other notes about your code:

1. You can destructure props for easier use.
2. You do not need a separate closing tag for `View` if there is no content.
3. You do not have to make new arrow functions for event handlers if all you are doing is calling another arrow function. You can just set it to the first arrow function.
4. Consider a ternary to allow an implicit return.

```
function RenderDish({dish, favorite, onFavorite, onComment}) =>
    dish
    ?   <Card featuredTitle={dish.name} image={{ uri: baseUrl + dish.image }}>
            <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                {dish.description}
            </Text>
            <View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Icon raised reverse name={favorite ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'} type='font-awesome' color='#f50'
                    onPress={() => favorite ? console.log('Aleady Favorite') : onFavorite()} />
                <Icon raised reverse name='pencil' type='font-awesome' color='#3b5998'
                    onPress={onComment} />
            </View>
        </Card>
    :   <View/>
```

I would focus more on these items, rather than bundling those two functions.